# Why does a human's field of view narrow when moving faster?

Tags: eyes, vision, anecdotal-evidence

A relative of mine is a driving instructor and he regularly likes to bring up that the field of view narrows noticeably when driving at higher speeds.
Is this true, why is this so and does this apply for other species as well (for example, leopards, who are widely known for their fast speed)?

Comment: Do you have a citation for this other than the anecdote? I did not notice this effect when looking out of the window in planes and high-speed trains, which travel much faster.

Comment: @MarchHo Sorry, I don't have a reference, updated the question. But as per airplanes, no object is actually moving fast in your field of view, as everything is far away.

Comment: I mean when looking at the runway moments before takeoff, or a parallel set of rails.

Comment: I believe your cousin is referring to what is usually called 'tunnel vision'

Comment: stuff on sides of your FOV are moving faster than in the center (right in the center speed is zero, actually). At some speed things on sides will just be a complete blur. Try looking from the window of moving car on hills far away and on the road barrier close to you: same thing for driver

Comment: I totally concur with @aandreev - the field of view is a constant (bar any medical issues) and will not change when moving about at any reasonable speed (at the speed of light things might change :-). Attentional focus (subjective percept) may change at high speeds, and physical retinal image slip indeed changes with visual angle as aandreev suggests.

Comment: Perhaps it has something to do with adrenalin discharge?